# JQuery reload three settings variables based on window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I am trying to load three setting variables for bxSlider, based on the size of the window. I want the new settings to load dynamically when the browser is resized, not just on load. I have the below code that is setting the variables, I'm just struggling with making it play nicely with the bottom variable of mySlider, which is what is laoding the script upon resize.

Can anybody offer tips?

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
        /* Set variables for the maxSlides option */
        var slidenumber,
            width = $(window).width();

        if (width < 768) {
            slidenumber = 1;
        } else if (width < 1024) {
            slidenumber = 2;
        } else {
            slidenumber = 3;
        }

        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            slideWidth: 5000,
            minSlides: slidenumber,
            maxSlides: slidenumber,
            slideMargin: 50
        });

        var mySlider;

        function tourLandingScript() {
            mySlider.reloadSlider(slidenumber());
        }

        mySlider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider(slidenumber());
        $(window).resize(tourLandingScript);

});
```

Comment: `slidenumber` is not a function. replace `slidenumber()` with `slidenumber`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Ondra Koupil for his help, however I was not able to get his solution to work exactly as required, I have ended up opting for an entirely new approach, which I'm sure could be pulled apart in order to optimise and is unlikely to be the most efficient option, but it works for me and hopefully can be of use to others.

The below solution is intended to be two entirely separate pieces of JS, which will not work if combined on one page. The intention is to load the relevant option (settings one/two) on the relevant page.

```
/* Settings one */
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var settings = function() {
    var settings1 = { /* Desktop */
            minSlides: 3,
            maxSlides: 3,
            moveSlides: 1,
            slideWidth: 5000, /* Intentionally set to high value, bxslider will auto calculate */
            slideMargin: 50
        };
        var settings2 = { /* Mobile */
            minSlides: 1,
            maxSlides: 1,
            moveSlides: 1,
            slideWidth: 2000 /* Intentionally set to high value, bxslider will auto calculate */
        };
        return ($(window).width()<1200) ? settings2 : settings1;
    }

    var mySlider;

    function reloadonresize() {
        mySlider.reloadSlider(settings());
    }

    mySlider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider(settings());
    $(window).resize(reloadonresize);


});
/* End settings */

/* Settings two */
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var settings = function() {
    var settings1 = { /* Desktop */
            minSlides: 4,
            maxSlides: 5,
            moveSlides: 3,
            slideWidth: 5000, /* Intentionally set to high value, bxslider will auto calculate */
            slideMargin: 50
        };
        var settings2 = { /* Mobile */
            minSlides: 2,
            maxSlides: 2,
            moveSlides: 1,
            slideWidth: 2000 /* Intentionally set to high value, bxslider will auto calculate */
        };
        return ($(window).width()>=768) ? settings1 : settings2;
    }

    var mySlider;

    function reloadonresize() {
        mySlider.reloadSlider(settings());
    }

    mySlider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider(settings());
    $(window).resize(reloadonresize);


});
/* End settings */
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to achieve this would be using CSS and media queries, so that you can hide or shrink slides without changing their number. However, if you need more complex behaviour that can't be achieved just with plain CSS, you'll need to write some javascript to it.

You need to listen to window's resize event and when it fires, recalculate required number of slides and if it changes, update slider using it's reloadSlider() method. The code could look somehow like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {     

    var slideCount;
    var mySlider;        

    // separate function to calculate required slide count
    function calculateSlides() {
        var width = $(window).width();
        var slidenumber;
        if (width < 768) {
            slidenumber = 1;
        } else if (width < 1024) {
            slidenumber = 2;
        } else {
            slidenumber = 3;
        }
        return slidenumber;
    }

    // when page loads, we initialize the slider
    slideCount = calculateSlides();
    mySlider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        slideWidth: 5000,
        minSlides: slideCount,
        maxSlides: slideCount,
        slideMargin: 50
    });

    // when we resize the window, just recalculate number of slides
    // and if it has changed, reload the slider

    $(window).resize(function() {
        var newSlideCount = calculateSlides();
        if (newSlideCount != slideCount) {
            slideCount = newSlideCount;
            mySlider.reloadSlider({
                minSlides: newSlideCount,
                maxSlides: newSlideCount 
            });
        }
    });

});
```

I also added some small optimization, so that browser won't rebuild whole slider component on every window resize (which triggers several times per second when resizing window by dragging its edge), but only in the moment when actual number of slides changes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Ondra, thank you for your help, this is almost perfect. This all loads correctly on initial load (varying by browser size), but does not change correctly during resize? For example, if loaded above 1024px, the three slides will display, but as you scale down (below 1024px) the slider reverts to just one slide. If you then increase the browser size, you are left with just the single slide. Any thoughts on how to improve this? Thanks

Comment: Well, there might be some caveat I am not aware of - I don't use bxSlider daily. Are you sure it supports changing number of slides dynamically? Maybe try adding some debug logging - i.e. `console.log(slideCount)` just before the line with reloadSlider(), and see what gets printed out. Then you'll see if the problem is in this script or if bxSlider just can't cope with changing slide count...

Comment: It definitely supports dynamic loading, as I had it working using a different piece of script previously, but I could only get it to support two sizes i.e below 768px or above. The script for that was found here. [link](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/JavaScript/Q_28291725.html)

Comment: Can anybody else shed any light on how to perfect the above code? It's very close but I have hit a brick wall...